# Enemy bot moves away from the player Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making top down shooting game. I wrote the code where enemies spawn randomly on map and they're trying to catch you. I made them do that and also I wrote a code to make them look at you. Basically rotate towards you only on Z axis. But problem is that when they are spawned on players' right, enemy is moving away from player. but if I rotate and start to move they are trying to fix themselves. Here's my script:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
        Vector3 difference = player.position - transform.position;
        float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);
        Vector2 toTarget = player.transform.position - transform.position;
        float speed = 1.5f;
         
        transform.Translate(toTarget * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider that `Translate` is a relative modifier. For this reason, when you specify the direction in the Translate itself, the movement becomes confused. Use `Vector3.MoveTowards` to solve the problem. If your game is 2D, you can also use `Vector2` like below:

```cs
Vector2.MoveTowards(currentPosition, targetPosition, step);
```

Preferably you can fix this code like this and set the return value of `MoveTowards` equal to `transform.Position`.

```cs
void FixedUpdate () {
    Vector3 difference = player.position - transform.position;
    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);
    float speed = 1.5f;
    
    // replace Translate to MoveTowards
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.position, Time.deltaTime * speed);
}
```